# Format datetime with addition of +02:00 (%z)

Tags: sesam

I have a datetime (UTC) which I want to change to Oslo timezone and format to include +02:00.

Input is eg. "~t2016-06-09T11:14:21Z".
Output should be: "2016-06-09T13:14:21+02:00"

I am trying with the following datetime-format, but with no luck:

```
["datetime-format", "Europe/Oslo", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", "_S.InstallationDate"]
```

According to the documentation %z is supported by datetime-parse. Is it not supported by datetime-format? How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported. A possible workaround is to format the timestamp with a fixed offset (in the example 2 hours) so that you can hardcode the offset in the string:

```
{
  "_id": "my-pipe",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "foo",
      "InstallationDate": "~t2016-06-09T11:14:21Z"
    }]
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["comment", "shift by 2 hours (one hour in nanoseconds is 3.6e12)"],
        ["add", "formatted+0200",
          ["concat",
            ["datetime-format", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z",
              ["datetime",
                ["+",
                  ["*", 2, 3600000000000],
                  ["integer", "_S.InstallationDate"]
                ]
              ]
            ], "+0200"]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This gives you:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "foo",
    "formatted+0200": "2016-06-09T13:14:21+0200"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late but on `22.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.5.0` (current macOS) the following worked straight away:

```
~ date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %z"
2023-07-31T11:13:21 +0200
```

I guess it will also work with most of the Linux variants of `date`.

Bonus: When you take capital `%Z` the timezone gets transscribe to a letterbased code, e.g.:

```
~ date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %Z"
2023-07-31T11:16:54 CEST
```